# SOLVED - Formulas paste as text and evaluated in the formula bar but not in the cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have tried this, but the formula seems to paste as text. It is evaluated in the formula bar, but not in the cell(s) housing the formula.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You would have to paste it into the cells that are using the formula. Why are you writing formulas in NP++ in the first place, where you can't test them, instead of writing them directly in the worksheet?

Comment: `Can you paste as formula written in NP++`? Yes! I've done this many times when I'm trying to build a complex formula referencing ranges on another sheet. You paste the text directly into the formula bar for the relevant cell. `It is evaluated in the formula bar, but not in the cell(s) housing the formula.` Would you give an example of this, as well as the result that you were expecting.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Though solved, to clarify the issue, I pasted "='Area Counts'!A6" from Notepad to a cell in google sheets. It showed the formula in the formula bar, and when I highlighted it in the formula bar, it was evaluated and the data I was expecting to be ported in popped up when I mouseOver the formula in the bar. The cell did not show the data I was expecting, just the literal of what I pasted, " ='Area Counts'!A6"

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] - When I paste the formlas in, they default to 'Automatic' format. I highlighted the afflicted cells containing the formulae and **FORMAT > Number**. The formulas were then seen as formulas and treated as such.